# Use URL query string in img src attribute

Tags: php, images

I'd like to display images of my custom fonts on my (private) WordPress site. The font-creation website I use, [FontStruct](http://fontstruct.com/), has a URL-accessed tool for rendering a line of text in a specific font. Here's an example URL:

```
http://static.fontstruct.com/render/934978.png?v=562f72c9&w=400&h=100&f=0x000000FF&t=<fs_lost>&a=left&s=0.5
```

This leads to [this image](http://static.fontstruct.com/render/934978.png?v=562f72c9&w=400&h=100&f=0x000000FF&t=<fs_lost>&a=left&s=0.5), which is what I'd like to put on my page. The problem is, when I paste this URL into an `<img>` tag and press "Preview", WordPress removes the query string from the URL in the resulting page. This makes it show up [like so](http://static.fontstruct.com/render/934978.png), which is not how I would prefer it to be. To fix this, I've tried:

- Replacing each ampersand with `%26`. Had no effect whatsoever.
- Replacing the question mark with `%3F`. The resulting URL contained an escaped question mark character instead of a query string.
- Inserting the following PHP code:

```php
<?php
    echo '&lt;img src="http://static.fontstruct.com/render/934978.png?v=562f72c9&w=1600&h=100&f=0x000000FF&t=fs_lost&a=left&s=0.5" /&gt;';
?>
```

But either this is invalid PHP (quite possible; I know very little PHP), or it's incorrect (I'm misunderstanding what it does); it's just not inserting the image into the page.

- Using this code for the `<img>` tag:

```html
<img src="&lt;?php echo 'http://static.fontstruct.com/render/934978.png?v=562f72c9&w=400&h=100&f=0x000000FF&t=fs_lost&a=left&s=0.5' ?&gt;" />
```

This almost works, but the image URL in the preview starts with `//static.fontstruct.com` and ends in `&s=0.5' ?>`.

I suppose one final option would be to upload two images for each font (I'd like to have a roll-over image as well, but haven't figured that out, either), but that would be quite time-consuming, and they'd need to be replaced anytime the font is updated.

So, is it possible to use the original URL in this case, and if not, is there a workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've used the URL `http://static.fontstruct.com/render/934978.png?v=562f72c9&w=400&h=100&f=0x000000FF&t=<fs_lost>&a=left&s=0.5` in the post editor of WordPress (using add media button) and it works perfectly, nothing is removed from query string and it is correctly scaped and encoded.

Comment: @cybmeta I hadn't realized that I could upload an image from a URL with Add Media. Thanks!

But unfortunately, having the arrow signs in the URL messes up the HTML, so the text `http://static.fontstruct.com/render/934978.png?v=562f72c9&w=400&h=100&f=0x00000‌​0FF&t=&a=left&s=0.5` (note the text missing after `&t=`) shows up on the page. Even if I remove the arrows, it seems that the query string is still left out. I don't think it's caching; changing the ID results in an image of `AaBbCc Handgloves` in another font. I have no idea what's going wrong....

Comment: I think you have not understood what I said. I use the Add Media button but I didn't upload any image; I used the "Insert from URL" option. You will get the image inserted correctly.

Comment: @cybmeta I believe I understand; like you, I am pressing the Add Media button, then going to the "Insert from URL" option. After this, I paste the URL and press "Insert into post"; then what I described in my first comment happens. This is the process you are describing, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is the same process but not the same results. It works correctly here.